# How do I upgrade qt version?

Tags: linux-mint, qt

I've been looking around for the answer to this, but the answers are all geared towards python developers. I am not a python developer but I need to upgrade my qt version so I can use the [ODA File Converter](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter) to open .dwg files in FreeCAD as per these [instructions](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/FreeCAD_and_DWG_Import).

Current qt version: 5.9.5 (I think, this is what the Software Manager says I have)
Required qt version: 5.14.1

How can I upgrade my qt version to the required version?

I am on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Downloading Qt

You can get the [latest Qt version](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run) installer from their [website](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/). Once downloaded go to your download directory, make the script executable and run it:

```bsh
cd ~/Downloads # assuming it is the download location
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
sudo ./qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
```

#### Installing Qt

Install Qt in the `opt` directory and select the version and the components needed. The installer will prompt you for your `sudo` password. You need to select at least the *Desktop gcc 64 bit* component of the needed version.

#### Configuring Qt

1. Create the configuration directory:

   - For system wide configuration create the `qtchooser` directory in  `/etc/xdg`.
   - For user specific configuration create the `qtchooser` directory in `~/.config`.
2. Create a `default.conf` file in the `qtchooser` directory of the previous step containing the following (replace the `x` by the desired Qt version):

```bsh
/opt/qt/5.xx.x/gcc_64/bin
/opt/qt/5.xx.x/gcc_64/lib
```

#### Check configuration

If the installation is properly configured the `qmake -v` command should return something like

```
QMake version x.x
Using Qt version 5.xx.x in /opt/qt/5.xx.x/gcc_64/lib
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat. Just to note. The install function should be run as sudo - `sudo ./qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run`. Without that it installed into the home directory for the current user. Had to remove and run again.